# Sum multiple large rasters using rasterio

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I have some issues trying to sum 15 rasters with these dimensions Col = 53241 rows=45598 cell size =30 meters, data type= float32. I used rasterio to perform this operation but I have a problem with memory. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

This the code

```
input=r'data folder path'
output=r'output path'

dir_list = os.listdir(input) 
merge_dir=[]
for filename in fnmatch.filter(dir_list,'*.tif'): 
  merge_dir.append((os.path.join(input, filename)))

map2array=[]
for raster in merge_dir:
    with rasterio.open(raster) as src:
        map2array.append(src.read().astype(np.float32))
        
profile=src.profile
profile.update(compress='lzw')

mosaic=np.nansum(map2array,0)

with rasterio.open(output, 'w', **profile) as dst:
   # Write to disk
   dst.write(mosaic)
```

**Unable to allocate 100.04 GiB for an array with shape (1, 45598, 53241) and data type float32**

Comment: Surely you don't need all 15 in memory at once to sum them? Can't you sum two, then add a third and discard it, then add a fourth and discard it and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways (there are some threads here in Stackoverflow about it) to improve performance and/or memory consumption while read, write and process large rasters. Here an example that uses a library called dask-raster for read/process/write using chunks or window blocks, I like it because its easy to use but you can also implement it in a pure dask:

```
import rasterio
import dask.array as da
from dask_rasterio import read_raster, write_raster
import os
import fnmatch

input_tif='data folder path'

merge_dir=[]
for filename in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(input_tif),'*.tif'): 
    merge_dir.append((os.path.join(input_tif, filename)))

map2array=[]
for raster in merge_dir:
    map2array.append(read_raster(raster, band=1, block_size=10))
    
ds_stack = da.stack(map2array)

with rasterio.open(merge_dir[0]) as src:
    profile=src.profile
    profile.update(compress='lzw')
    
write_raster("output.tif", da.nansum(ds_stack,0), **profile)
```